# FPDF tables next to each other

Tags: php, html, fpdf

[image: Calendar year view]

I'm trying to create a calendar PDF with FPDF like the image above, but my tables are displayed among themselves. Here's what I get:

[image]

I'm using this script: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php
which allows me to convert HTML tables to PDF.

I am very grateful if someone has an idea how I can implement this or someone knows another tool for this problem.

Comment: Not quite sure what 'among themselves means'. Can you add a screenshot of what you are getting.
And, fwiw, tables-within-tables is a standard way to get things to group together using html, so maybe something like that will work with you in fpdf. (I don't have an example lying around to prove that, but think about it.)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZwa2.png that's what i get. Yes, good point, I tried to do it in 1 big table for each "line" but it didn't work out quite well. I will try further.

Comment: hi there . did u get what u want ..? bcz im facing almost same case as u now ... i hope u can share with us how u solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`setXY`](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setxy.htm) function to move your current position on the page everytime you start drawing a table. After every table row, the current position will go all the way back to the left margin instead of your previous X position, but you can use [`SetLeftMargin`](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setleftmargin.htm) to solve that.

The example below uses the script that you linked to. You can tweak the numbers or do some smarter size calculations. I printed the same table 12 times to keep the example code short.

```
<?php
require('html_table.php');
$pdf = new PDF('L');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

$html = '<table border="1">
<tr><td width="100" height="50">cell 1</td><td width="100" height="50">cell 2</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100" height="50">cell 3</td><td width="100" height="50">cell 4</td></tr>
</table>';

// 'origin' is the top left of the January table:
$originX = 10;
$originY = 50;
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    // Move 70mm to the right after every month:
    $x = $originX + ($i % 4) * 70;
    // Move 60mm down after every 4 months:
    $y = $originY + floor($i / 4) * 60;
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin($x);
    $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```